# Using nvm (0.39.1) and Node.js (18.15.0), getting error "yargs supports a minimum Node.js version of 12"

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nvm, localtunnel

using ubuntu 20.04.6

when running command
`sudo lt --port 25565`
I get the output

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/localtunnel/node_modules/yargs/build/index.cjs:1
"use strict";var t=require("assert");class e extends Error{constructor(t){super(t||"yargs error"),this.name="YError",Error.captureStackTrace(this,e)}}let s,n=[];function i(t,o,a,h){s=h;let l={};if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t,"extends")){if("string"!=typeof t.extends)return l;const r=/\.json|\..*rc$/.test(t.extends);let h=null;if(r)h=function(t,e){return s.path.resolve(t,e)}(o,t.extends);else try{h=require.resolve(t.extends)}catch(e){return t}!function(t){if(n.indexOf(t)>-1)throw new e(`Circular extended configurations: '${t}'.`)}(h),n.push(h),l=r?JSON.parse(s.readFileSync(h,"utf8")):require(t.extends),delete t.extends,l=i(l,s.path.dirname(h),a,s)}return n=[],a?r(l,t):Object.assign({},l,t)}function r(t,e){const s={};function n(t){return t&&"object"==typeof t&&!Array.isArray(t)}Object.assign(s,t);for(const i of Object.keys(e))n(e[i])&&n(s[i])?s[i]=r(t[i],e[i]):s[i]=e[i];return s}function o(t){const e=t.replace(/\s{2,}/g,"

Error: yargs supports a minimum Node.js version of 12. Read our version support policy: https://github.com/yargs/yargs#supported-nodejs-versions
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/localtunnel/node_modules/yargs/build/index.cjs:1:57316)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/localtunnel/node_modules/yargs/index.cjs:5:30)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
```

Output of `nvm -ls` is

```
      v12.22.12
       v16.20.0
->     v18.15.0
         system
default -> 16.20 (-> v16.20.0)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v18.15.0) (default)
stable -> 18.15 (-> v18.15.0) (default)
lts/* -> lts/hydrogen (-> v18.15.0)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.12
lts/fermium -> v14.21.3 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.20.0
lts/hydrogen -> v18.15.0
```

which leads me to think there is some kind of issue beyond node.js.
I cant decipher any of this stuff, Thanks for any help!

I already tried reinstalling node.js and nvm and `sudo apt update`